# Configure routing on Windows 10 with dual IP to connect via TeamViewer

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I have the following setup: a "gateway" computer running Windows 10 with two simultaneous network connections.

1. connected to the internet via cable (IP 192. ...)
2. connected to a secured network via WLAN (IP 10. ...)

The purpose of this setup is to connect to the gateway computer via TeamViewer which should listen to incoming connections via the cable, then, once connected, the user should be able to access the secured network.

This does work as long as the WLAN is not connected when establishing the connection through TeamViewer. The user is able to connect to the gateway computer, can activate WLAN (connection to the gateway computer persists) and access the secured network.
The problem: If WLAN stays activated when the TeamViewer-session is terminated, TeamViewer on the gateway computer seems to "forget" to listen on incoming connections through the cable connection (presumably it now listens through the WLAN connection), so no user is able to connect to the gateway computer anymore. If WLAN is disconnected before terminating the TeamViewer-session, everything's fine, the next user can connect without any problems.

Question: How do I need to configure Windows to have TeamViewer keep listening to incoming connections through the cable and not through WLAN while keeping the gateway computer connected to the WLAN all the time?

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Windows doesn't support this right away, but the desired setup can be achieved by using the program [ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip), e.g. like this:

```
ForceBindIP.exe 192.168.0.1 "C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe"
```

will bind TeamViewer to 192.168.0.1 (replace with the IP of the network it should listen to). Seems pretty convenient, as it doesn't change any of the Windows config but rather launches the program with a different setting (that's gone again if you start the program normally).